# Rails' send_data: wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I've a method in my controller:

```
def send_data
    send_data "one,two,three", "file.csv"
  end
```

When I go to `root.com/send_data` I get this error message:

```
ArgumentError in PagesController#send_data

wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
```

[APIDock claims it takes in two arguments](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data).

What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You define the `send_data` method in your controller. Your `send_data` takes 0 parameters. Rename your method.